# Python: 'GridSearchCV' object has no attribute 'coef_'

Tags: python, logistic-regression

I am trying to return the coefficients of my logistic regression model. Here is how I created my model:

```
logreg = LogisticRegression(solver = 'liblinear')

model = GridSearchCV(logreg, cv = 3, param_grid = {
    'penalty': ('l1', 'l2'),
    'C': [0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9],
    'max_iter': [100]
})

model.fit(X_train, y_train)
model.coef_ # here is where I get the error
# Validation (test)
y_pred = model.predict(X_test)
```

But I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'GridSearchCV' object has no attribute 'coef_'
```

I even tried the .best_score_ and other functions to see if I could find the coefficients in another way. But no luck. Do you know how I can fix this?

Answer (score 4):

You have to select a specific estimator to access the `coef_` property. Try:

```
model.best_estimator_.coef_
```

The `GridSearchCV` object itself doesn't have a coefficient, because it's not an estimator, it's an object that cycles through parameters and trains various estimators.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried it and again I got the similar  error: 'GridSearchCV' object has no attribute 'best_estimator_'

Comment: If you did what I wrote it's impossible that you received the _same_ error

Comment: Ok, I was trying it in a new cell in jupyter notebook and thought it would work. But put it right after fit and now it working. thanks!

Comment: Did you 1) somehow set `refit=False` or 2) not run `.fit` when you tested the code?

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for the best model provided by `GridSearchCV`:

```py
...
model.fit(X_train, y_train)
best_model = model.best_estimator_
best_model.coef_ # This should be what you're looking for

y_pred = best_model.predict(X_test)
```

Your model is simply a `GridSearchCV` object whereas `coef_` is an attribute of a logreg object. The `best_estimator_` attribute is the estimator with highest accuracy found during grid search.